# How to do javascript bootstrap form validation?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, bootstrap-5

There is a standard bootstrap validation script:

```
 'use strict'

  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function (form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        } 
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
})()
```

But it only checks if the values ​​are empty. And I need to additionally check, for example, that the input field with id=year has four digits.
I know about "pattern" attribute, but Safari doesn't support it. I need a javascript solution with a code example.

Comment: `the input field with id=year has four digits` ... you could try getting the field values in question and doing some custom validation via javascript. "Bootstrap" is not what this about.

Comment: Yes, and I need an example of such a script that is compatible with the standard script.